Reference request: handbook of probability distributions
Does there exist a "handbook of probability distributions" akin to the "Related distributions" section on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_distribution#Properties. In other words the book should contain lots of distributions and how they are related to each other via operations on random variables.

I had asked a similar question long ago here
